# Tab Menus: Change what tab is focused on page load?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

At the bottom of [this page](http://ryanspahn.com/avia8/features.html) I have a tab menu.  It works, but we need the 2nd tab to be focused "current release," on page load and not the first ("previous release").

I've tried different things (added `class="active"` to the 2nd tab's `li`), but no success thus far.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably generally better to do this on the server, but if you're OK with a client-side solution (since the question is tagged jQuery), you could just do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul .current-release').click();
});
```

Comment: awesome jmar, that was the simple solution i was seeking!

Comment: Maybe you might have a solution or suggestion for the image rollovers there?  When active or hovered they need to be as how I have the nav menu at the top.  thanks again!

Comment: In your CSS, you could try something like: `.active .current-release, .current-release:hover {
    background-image: url("../images/current-release-active-trans.png"); }`  You'll need that for each of the other tabs links as well, of course.

Comment: awesome thanks again jmar!  Though just one last thing ... the first nav image "previous release," jumps around?  Any idea what maybe causing that?

Comment: No problem. You're setting the margin-left to 0 (in short-hand format, anyway) for the active and hover states, which causes it to "jump" to the left.  You shouldn't need to reset margins, width, height, etc. on your hover and active states - just inherit those from the normal state.  Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that you are not using the jQuery UI Tabs. I think you should seriously thinking about switching to it. It makes your life much easier. Take a look at the demos: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/.

Once you're using jQuery UI Tabs, you can simply initiate the tabs with the `selected` option:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 1 });
```

Comment: He's not using jQueryUI tabs - just a small script in the javascript.js file.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after taking a second look, hence the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should find out how focusing works for the first tab. Have it `active` class on `li` element or on some other element inside that?

Second you should see if there is any client-side script at work or not? Some tab-based systems like Telerik Tabs use cookies and client-side JavaScript to focus the current tab.

Third you should see if the tab doesn't get highlighted and focused from server. Sometimes in spite of all client-side attempt, server does something behind the scenes. (Of course this has meaning, only if you haven't written the server-side code).